# How to add a new line for django model field's verbose name

Tags: django

For example, I want to show:

```
Phone num:
(电话)
```

instead of:

```
Phone num: (电话)
```

I'ved tried both:

```
phone_number = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"Phone num: <br>(电话)", max_length=10)
phone_number = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"Phone num: \n(电话)", max_length=10)
```

but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can define a simple_tag. For example, i have a field with verbose_name = "abc mybr def". I define my tag as :

@register.simple_tag

def mylabel_tag(label_tag):

```
# label_tag = "<label for=\"id_moca_013_1\">abc mybr def:</label>"
ss = re.split(">|<|mybr", label_tag)
ans = "<" + ss[1] + ">" + ss[2] + "</label><br>" + \
      "<" + ss[1] + ">" + ss[3] + "</label><br>"

return ans
```

in html:

{% mylabel_tag field.label_tag %}

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this will work:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

phone_number = models.CharField(verbose_name=mark_safe(u'Phone num: <br />(电话)'), max_length=10)
```